# Header stick to the top when apps scrolled

Tags: react-native

How do I make a header stick to the top like `SectionList` does. What I meant is the section header. Is there any package for this? As you can see example below, see the sticky section header on both apps

[image: flickr with grid view]
[image: alibaba]

Comment: Can you show required UI?

Comment: move the header out of the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

If you put your content in a `ScrollView` and your Header the first element. You can set `ScrollView#stickyHeaderIndices` to [0]. This property take an array of all sticky element indice.

```
<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}>
    <Header />
    <View />
    <View />
    <View />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is a Snack [Sticky Header on ScrollView](https://snack.expo.io/@mcssym/stickyheader-on-scrollview)

Comment: what is the output for this? Could you provide any gif

Comment: Here is a Snack https://snack.expo.io/@mcssym/stickyheader-on-scrollview

Comment: That’s not what I meant. Look at the SectionList section header does. The reason I can’t use sectionList is because I can’t arrange the item in grid.